# jquery scrolltop scrolls two scroll position

Tags: jquery

I have a code that will get `scroll position` of a `div` then animate a scroll to it whenever a button is triggered. But if I click that button a second time it always scroll my screen into different scroll position.

Here's my code:

```
<style>

#tall{
    height: 2000px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#drag_contact{
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

#contact{
    position: fixed;
}

</style>

<script src="css/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="development-bundle/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact").click(function(){
        var offset = $("#drag_contact").offset();
        var w = $(window);

        var top = offset.top-w.scrollTop();
        $("body, html").animate({scrollTop:top});

    });
})

</script>

<body>

<button id='contact' >contact</button>
<div id='tall' >
</div>

<div id='drag_contact' ></div>

</body>
```

Hope it will solve :) Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you please provie a JSFiddle on http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic was a bit off. The current `window.scrollTop` isn't relevant:

http://jsfiddle.net/tS8md/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact").click(function(){
        var offset = $("#drag_contact").offset();
        $("body, html").animate({scrollTop:offset.top});

    });
})
```